# How to reshape or clean data to be able to visualize it with violin plots?

Tags: python, visualization, data-cleaning, transformation

My end goal is to visualize some data using a violin plot or something similar using Python.

I have the following data in a file (`test.csv`). The first column is a list of species. The other columns determine abundance of the species at a certain latitude (e.g. how abundant is species A at altitude 1000, 2000?). (Ignoring units for now.) How can I plot this as a violin plot (or something similar)?

**test.csv**

```
species,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000
species_A,0.5,0.5,,,2,1,2
species_B,0.5,1,0.5,0.5,1,1,10
species_C,1,1,10,3,15,4,5
species_D,15,3,2,1,0.5,1,3
```

The Python code I tried so far is below. This does not work because it only plots the distribution of altitudes, which is the same for all species (because they were all sampled from the same set of altitudes).

````
file = "test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)

# convert columns to list
colnames = list(df.columns)
colnames.remove("species")

# Transform the data so that I have a dataframe with only three columns: species, Altitude, and Count
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['species'], value_vars=colnames, value_name="Count", var_name="Altitude")
df.species = df.species.astype('category')
df.Altitude = df.Altitude.astype('int')

# Plot the data
sns.violinplot(x="species", y="Altitude", data=df)
plt.title("Abundance of Species at Various Altitudes")
plt.grid(alpha=0.5, ls="--")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

# show graph
plt.show()
```
````

Comment: It sounds like you have three variables: species, location, and abundance. Is this correct? Such data are not amenable to a box plot or violin plot, as those would be for just the categorical species variable and one of the numerical variables. My first visualization would be a scatter plot of the location and abundance with different colors and/or shapes for the species: lions in red, tigers in blue, and bears in black, for instance.

Comment: @Dave My data counts the number of species at a given altitude: *x* species A at altitude *y*. To me (at least), it doesn't seem too different than the *life_exp* vs *continent* plot [this this tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/seaborn-violin-plot-tutorial-and-examples).

Comment: The x-axis in their chart is the continent; the y-axis is the `life_exp`. You have a third dimension. I still recommend a bivariate scatter plot with your categorical variable denoted by colors, shapes, or both. That captures all three of your variables.

Comment: @Dave My data could be reshaped to two variables: species and location. Using my example data: there would be 2 entries for species A at altitude 7000, 1 entry at altitude 6000, etc. (The 0.5 entries can either be omitted or rounded up/down.)

Comment: Then make a violin chart with categorical species on the x-axis and numerical altitude on the y-axis. That is analogous to the plot in the link, but it does omit the abundance variable.

Comment: Oh, do you mean that there are 50 lions, 9 tigers, and 13 bears at altitude 1; 9 lions, 11 tigers, and 61 bears at altitude 2; etc?

Comment: @Dave That's correct.

Comment: Then you have 50 observations of (lion, 1), 9 observations of (lion, 2), 61 observations of (bear, 2), etc. Make your data frame that way, and then you have two variables for your violin plot: categorical `species` on the x-axis and numerical `altitude` on the y-axis.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's an easy way to do it? Seems like what I want is that does the opposite of pandas' `group()` method. Whatever, I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new Pandas DataFrame using the code below. I wash hoping for something simpler or more elegant.

```
# Create a new dataframe
df_2d = pd.DataFrame()
for _, sp in df.iterrows():
    count = 0 if np.isnan(sp['Count']) else int(np.ceil(sp['Count']))
    df_2d = df_2d.append([{"species": sp["species"], "Altitude": sp["Altitude"]}] * count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the "ungrouped" dataframe by reindexing on a repeated index:

```py
df_2d = df.loc[df.index.repeat(
    df["Count"].fillna(0).astype(int)
)]
```

There should be a more direct way to generate a plot,  but I don't know it. That your latitudes are discretized might not help.